# How to display last div at top using CSS?

Tags: css, layout, html

I have 4 different divs. The last one is footer. How can I put the last div at top using CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<div id = "FooterAtTop">what ever here</div>
```

put this in CSS file or in `<style>` in head:

```
#FooterAtTop

{
position: absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
}
```

Though if you want to keep it floating do this:

```
#FooterAtTop
{
position: fixed;
top:0px;
left:0px;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The last one is the footer but you want to put it at the top ? I'm not sur what you want to do ^^

With JS you could achieve it without doubt.

Maybe could you explain a little bit your situation :-) and when do you want to put the last one to footer (after page is loaded ?)

But with this it should work :

```
.class1 { position:absolute; top:0; left:0; }
```

But be sure that your class1 is wraped in another class2 which contains :

```
.class2 { position:relative; }
```

Comment: <div id="1">first div</div>
<div id="2">second div</div>
<div id="3">3rd div</div>
<div id="footer">footer</div>

Comment: actually, divs are already there and I want to use CSS to put the footer at different positions.

Comment: Yes but you want to put the footer at different position after page is loaded or by editing your code ? By the way, code of @Anubhav Saini should work too.